# Array.prototype.map() expects a return value from arrow function

Tags: react, api, react-hooks, async-await

Estou tentando montar uma tabela com os resultados de uma API usando react, mas a tabela simplesmente não aparece, e na arrow function do meu map está dando esse erro: Array.prototype.map() expects a return value from arrow function. Aqui é o componente onde eu montei a tabela:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function Table() {
  const [planetsArr, setPlanetsArr] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const planetsInfos = async () => {
      const url = 'https://swapi.dev/api/planets';
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data.results);
      setPlanetsArr(data.results);
    };
    planetsInfos();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>NOME</td>
            <td>ROTAÇÃO</td>
            <td>PERIODO ORBITAL</td>
            <td>DIAMETRO</td>
            <td>CLIMA</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {planetsArr.map((el) => {
            <tr key={ el.name }>
              <td>{el.name}</td>
              <td>{el.rotation_period}</td>
              <td>{el.orbital_period}</td>
              <td>{el.diameter}</td>
              <td>{el.climate}</td>
            </tr>;
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Table;
```

no console.log eu consigo ver o retorno do array com o meu objeto certinho, mas os dados dos planetas não renderizam

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Como o erro informa, dê um return dentro da arrow function:

```
<tbody>
   {planetsArr.map((el) => {
      return <tr key={ el.name }>
         <td>{el.name}</td>
         <td>{el.rotation_period}</td>
         <td>{el.orbital_period}</td>
         <td>{el.diameter}</td>
         <td>{el.climate}</td>
      </tr>;
    })}
</tbody>
```

Comment: obrigado, era isso mesmo ^^ uma coisa tão simples como a falta de um retorno pode fazer a gente quebrar tanto a cabeça